# external facing sharepoint site users are not able to check out documents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have an external facing sharepoint site , thre are two type of users

Internal users and external users

Internal users = all employees who have AD accounts , employees are able to checkout documents when they are either using the VPN or in the Network , but once they are out of the network or not on vpn they get an error [image]

if user on network they dont have to go via the TMG and can access the site using http

but if you are not on the domain or vpn then the user has to go via tmg and it uses https

is this something to do with the port ?

It happens across all browsers (IE , firefox Chrome)

SharePoint 2010 -- config

2 WFE's -- 1 app server  1-- sql server

TIA

Comment: What happens if they click on "Check-Out" from the Edit Control Block (ECB) menu for the document in question? Do they get the same error?

Comment: yes same thing . The same user who is on vpn can edit it fine

Comment: You might want to look into alternate access mapping in Central Admin for them. It could be because their external credentials are not coming accross AD the same as when they are on VPN or on the local domain.

Comment: Is it a safe assumption that your external users don't have AD accounts? If this is correct where are their accounts created/managed?

Comment: All users have a AD accounts. even external users . We have a BI site so that vendors can access sql cube reports either via excel or SharePoint .is it something to do with the port like https = 80 and https is on a different port ?

Comment: @lazoDev I checked aam in CA , internal url http ://sharepoint.contoso.com  public url [http: //sharepoint.contoso.com] , should i also include [https ://sharepoint.contoso.com ?]

Comment: I would.  I believe unless you are within the domain, the credentials might differ and not allow users to certain information; for example, I have to use this when I create list connected to my external SQL database.  SharePoint expects, and also sends out, your AD credentials.  So I need AAM to let SharePoint now to use the right credentials for access to the database and not to use SharePoints.  I think this goes both ways.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I tested the same  document on another sharepoint site(no tmg , no HTTPS)I can checkout , check in the file no problem , so now that i see it is a https issue how do i resolve it ? TIA